# Faster search method on the first empty cell in a column using openpyxl PYTHON 3.5

Tags: python, search, xlsx, openpyxl

I am having a problem in searching a the first empty cell in a certain column 
on a 40k lines .xlsx file. As the search goes farther, it becoming slower and slower. Is there a faster/instant search method in searching the first empty cell on a column?

```
    wb = load_workbook(filename = dest_filename,read_only=True)
    sheet_ranges1 = wb[name]
    i = 1 
    x = 0
    sam = 0
    cc = 0
    brgyst =Street+Brgy
    entrylist = [TotalNoConfig,TotalNoChannel,Rsl,Mode,RslNo,Year,IssuedDate,Carrier,CaseNo,Site,brgyst,Municipality,Province,Region,Longitude1,Longitude2,Longitude3,Latitude1,Latitude2,Latitude3,ConvertedLong,ConvertedLat,License,Cos,NoS,CallSign,PTSVC,PTSVCCS,Tx,Rx] #The values to be inputted in the entire row after searching the last empty cell in column J
    listX1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N', 'O','P','Q','T','U','V','R','X','Y','Z','AA','AB','AM','AN','AP','FL'] #The columns in the file
    eter = 0      
    while(x != 1):
        cellS = 'J'+str(i) #until there is no empty cell
        if(sheet_ranges1[cellS].value is None): #if found empty cell, insert the values
            x=1
            book = load_workbook(filename = dest_filename)
            sheet = book[name]
            rangeof = int(len(entrylist))
            while(cc<rangeof):
                cells = listX1[cc]+str(i)
                sheet[cells]= entrylist[cc]    
                cc=cc+1                               
        else:
            x=0
        sam = sam+1   
        i=i+1
    wb.save(dest_filename)
    wb.close()
```

Comment: Solved question

Comment: enter at least 15

Comment: characters inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In read-only mode every cell lookup causes the worksheet to parsed again so you should always use `ws.iter_rows()` for your work.